# All recent changes in MySQL have been automatically removed. Recently INSERTed or UPDATEd data is not available

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have been using MySQL for the last two months. I'm regularly `INSERT`ing new records and `UPDATE`ing old ones. But when I opened phpMyAdmin today, all of the changes which I've made in the 10 days have vanished.

`INSERT`ed data for the last 10 days is unavailable and The `UPDATE`s I have made to other records have also reverted to previous versions.

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` field is still incrementing to the next number like nothing is `DELETE`d.

I need my recently `INSERT`ed data and my `UPDATE`s restored.

More importantly perhaps, **why** is this happening?

This problem happen between 5th to 7th January. This is the Error file of these days:
[Error Log](https://pastebin.com/E38wTqQ7)

Comment: Are you running all queries through phpmyadmin?  What setting do you have for autocommit?  Have you used any transactions?

Comment: No, I run maximum queries through php scripting. and I haven't make any changes in auto commit since i install MySQL

Comment: first thing  ckeck teh mysql error log for clues

Answer (score 0):

1. `set autocommit=OFF`
2. Do lots of `INSERTs`/`UPDATEs`/`DELETEs`
3. disconnect

Step 3 will do an implicit `ROLLBACK` since there was no `COMMIT`.  And this is why I advise against ever using `autocommit=OFF`.

And, yes, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` would not be reset.  That's just one of the quirks of auto_inc.  (Actually, it is an efficiency measure.)

So... either

```
SET autocommit=ON;
```

and leave it that way.  Check the configuration, too.  Or use transactions:

```
BEGIN;
inserts, etc
COMMIT;
```

Comment: How could  i get the data and update I have made? Is there any way?

Comment: _If_ the theory I spelled out is what happened, the data was thrown away by the Rollback.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto%';`  And experiment with adding more rows, followed promptly by checking the table's contents.

Comment: `+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
| autocommit               | ON    |
| automatic_sp_privileges  | ON    |
+--------------------------+-------+`

Comment: Since autocommit is 'ON'. and i haven't use any transaction. So, Perhaps it's not the matter of Rollback. Is there any reason near to it?

Comment: Is it possible to check whether a rollback happen or not by `show status like 'com_rollback%'   `. i have run it and it's like `+---------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name             | Value |
+---------------------------+-------+
| Com_rollback              | 0     |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint | 0     |
+---------------------------+-------+`

Comment: @RakibulIslam - Sorry, I have run out of ideas.  (I'm leading my Answer in place as a warning to others.)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Would you please look into error log file i have updated in question. I really don't understand which thing could be the reason in log.

Comment: @RakibulIslam - Hmmmm -- No hint that those restarts were crashes.  Possibly this might give a clue:  Turn on the "general log" until the next crash.  It _might_ say what was running at the time of the crash.